# Error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." while store date formate is dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql-server

How to resolve this error in SQL Server:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

My query is:

```
Insert into Pedido (FechaPedido, FechaTipoPedido) 
Values('13-03-2018', '13-03-2018')
```

Comment: Don't use non-deterministic date formats. use `yyyyMMdd`: `INSERT INTO Pedido (FechaPedido, FechaTipoPedido) VALUES ('20180313', '20180313');` This avoids problems with things like languages, where 13-03-2018 can be interpreted as either the 13th day of the 3rd month **or** the 3rd day of the 13th month (which doens't exist)

Comment: Formats have no dates, they are binary values. There are several dozen duplicate questions. The answers are always the same. *Don't* use strings at all to pass data from clients, use parameterized queries with strongly typed parameters. If you *have* to use strings, eg in an ad-hoc query, use *unambiguous* date literals. There are only two, the unseparated `YYYYMMDD` format for dates, and the full ISO8601 for datetime, ie `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`

Comment: In this case you tried to insert a month 13 to a server configured with a US locale

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for your replay . but requirement to store date format as above mention.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store dates in a format. It's stores dates as a date; you do the formatting in the presentation layer. Regardless of how you intially pass the date (for example `dd-MM-yyyy`, `MM/dd/yyyy` or `yyyyMMdd`) the data will be stored identically; provided to implicit conversion was successful. if you then need to show the format in a specific way, you set that in your presentation layer; not in your data engine.

Comment: There are not many certainties in system design, but you can be sure that if you are not using a date data type to store this then you are definitely doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your strings to dates indicating their format.

```
Insert into Pedido (FechaPedido, FechaTipoPedido) 
Values(convert(date, '13-03-2018', 105), convert(date, '13-03-2018', 105))
```

Concretely you are using the format 105 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting them in the 'expected' SQL date format.

```
INSERT INTO Pedido (FechaPedido, FechaTipoPedido) VALUES ('20180313', '20180313')
```

Comment: The "standard" SQL date format is `yyyyMMdd` not `yyyy-MM-dd`; the latter is the default display format for SSMS. If you're using `datetime`, rather than `date` then `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018-03-13);` is probably going to fail; regardless of your language setting. This is why you should always use `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss`.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with you that it is better to explicitly define the date format. However, for the sake of this question, I believe it is fine to use the format I proposed. Btw, it will not fail for the command you mentioned: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018-03-13');`  (you had a quote missing - if that is what is giving you an error).

Comment: I'd simply missed the end `'` off. `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018-03-13');` still presents the error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`. That's because SQL Server is interpreting the `13` and the months and `03` as the days (at least when using the British language). The format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) is not unambiguous and hence why `'20180313'` (`yyyyMMdd`) is the better format..

Comment: @Larnu Although I don't get the error, you convinced me that (`yyyyMMdd`) is a better format :P. I have now edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Apostolos I do not get the error either in a German setting, but in a British setting, it might be thrown.